# active class menu item on javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've menu items code....and I want if I click on menu a it will displaying a page, if I click on menu b it will displaying page b with out page a....

Can anyone show me how to solve this with `javascript` or `php`, I'm newbie.... please help..

This is my `HTML` code

```
<div class="col-xs-9">
  <ul class="menu-items">
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li>b</li>
  </ul>
  <div style="width:100%;border-top:1px solid silver">
    <p style="padding:15px;">page a</p>
  </div>
  <div class="attr1" style="width:100%;border-top:1px solid silver">
    <p>page b</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to hide page b,give id's to your div to show/hide via javascript:

```
<div class="col-xs-9">
    <ul class="menu-items">
        <li id="showA" class="active"></li>
        <li id="showB">b</li>

    </ul>
    <div id="pageA" style="width:100%;border-top:1px solid silver">
        <p style="padding:15px;">
            page a
        </p>
    </div>
     <div id="PageB" class="attr1" style="width:100%;border-top:1px solid silver;display:none">
        <p>page b</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript code to show particular page:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showA").click(function() {
            $("#pageB).hide();
            $("#pageA").show();
     });

     $("#showB").click(function() {
            $("#pageA).hide();
            $("#pageB").show();
     });
</script>
```

To set your menu active use following code:

```
$(".menu-items li").click(function() {
   $(".menu-items li").removeClass("active);
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: You might want to get in the habit of accepting answers if they solve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

you mean you want to open a new page when you click on list item, so just do this `window.open(pass your page url here)`

```html
<div class="col-xs-9">
  <ul class="menu-items">
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li>b</li>
  </ul>
  <div style="width:100%;border-top:1px solid silver">
    <p style="padding:15px;">page a</p>
  </div>
  <div class="attr1" style="width:100%;border-top:1px solid silver">
    <p onclick="function(){window.open(pageUrl)}">page b</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thats not new page, but something like container which when i click a it will show div a, n when i click b it will show div b n hiding div a